# How to sync the speed of a rigidbody and the speed of a running animation

Tags: unity, c#

I have a character with a run animation. The animation was downloaded from mixamo.com.
In the animation controller, the physical update mode is selected.
How do I change the speed of an animation based on the speed of a rigid body?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a Blend Tree.

In your Animator controller create a speed parameter as float and create Blend Tree.
[image]

In your Blend Tree, add motions and select your animations. (Image is from example 2D Blend Type, you can choose 1D if that's what you need). Numbers in Pos Y is max speed, if speed goes above then you may want to transition into another animation.

[image: Example image of Motions in Blend Tree]

Choose Blend Type and Parameters (in Blend Tree) as in this case parameter is SPEED_VARAIBLE.
[image: Examples of parameters in Blend Tree]

```
GetComponent<Animator>().SetFloat(ANIMATOR_KEY, SPEED_VARAIBLE);
```

Here's the link to documentation https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/class-BlendTree.html